# ASP.NET MVC DropDownList and HTML Attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I am having a dropdownlist in my application in edit form. 
But somewhere I was wrong.

---

*HomeController.cs*

```
        ViewData["RealizatorID"] = from r in db.tGlavnas
           select new SelectListItem { Text = r.Realizator.ImeRealizatora, 
           Value = r.Realizator.ImeRealizatora, Selected = (r.RealizatorID == id) };
```

---

*Edit.aspx*

```
        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.RealizatorID) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.DropDownList("RealizatorID")%>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RealizatorID) %>
        </div>
```

---

When recording changes in Edit.aspx page report following error to me:

There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'RealizatorID'.

Comment: OK I saw your full code of the action method. So the natural follow up is that you put the full code of your view. Where is your view posting to? It seems that you're not setting the viewdata after the submit.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do the following:

Controller:

```
ViewData["SelRealizator"] = from r in db.tGlavnas
           select new SelectListItem { Text = r.Realizator.ImeRealizatora, 
           Value = r.Realizator.ImeRealizatora, Selected = (r.RealizatorID == id) };
```

View:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.RealizatorID) %>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RealizatorID, ViewData["SelRealizator"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)%>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RealizatorID) %>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when I write this the error is:

There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'RealizatorID'.

Comment: That's weird, i'm pretty sure it should work. Please post the full code of your controller method

Answer (score 0):

Full code:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var log = db.tGlavnas.Single(lo => lo.RedniBroj == id);

        ViewData["SelRealizator"] = from r in db.tGlavnas select new SelectListItem { Text = r.Realizator.ImeRealizatora, Value = r.Realizator.ImeRealizatora, Selected = (r.RealizatorID == id) };
        return View(log);
    }
```

I don't write Post method yet.

Answer (score 0):

Edit.aspx

```
<h2>Edit</h2>
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.RedniBroj) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RedniBroj) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RedniBroj) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.DatumPrijema) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DatumPrijema) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DatumPrijema) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.DatumPredaje) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DatumPredaje) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DatumPredaje) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.BrojID) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BrojID) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BrojID) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.PredmetJavneNabavke) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PredmetJavneNabavke) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PredmetJavneNabavke) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.VrstaID) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.VrstaID) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VrstaID) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.TipSredstvaID) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TipSredstvaID) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TipSredstvaID) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProcenjenaVrednost) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ProcenjenaVrednost) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProcenjenaVrednost) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.PoKontuID) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PoKontuID) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PoKontuID) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.RealizatorID) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RealizatorID, ViewData["SelRealizator"] as 
                IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)%>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RealizatorID) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.PonudjacID) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PonudjacID) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PonudjacID) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Iznos) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Iznos, String.Format("{0:F}", Model.Iznos)) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Iznos) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.BrojRacuna) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BrojRacuna) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BrojRacuna) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.DatumIsplate) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DatumIsplate, String.Format("{0:g}", Model.DatumIsplate)) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DatumIsplate) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.JavnaNabSprovPostID) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.JavnaNabSprovPostID) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JavnaNabSprovPostID) %>
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

<% } %>

<div>
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
</div>
```